# Getting "authentication required" when setting SetIsHosted(true) for local debugging

Tags: c#, azure-mobile-services

Greets!

With Visual Studio 2013 Community, I create a new project using the Mobile Service template.  The only thing I add to the WebApiConfig.cs is config.SetIsHosted(true) so I can debug locally.  However, I am being asked for authentication creds.  Any ideas?  I need this so I can test the authentication and authorization inside the "Try it Out" link.  Without SetIsHosted, IIS will ignore any authentication.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WYFd.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test that page, you can use the application key for your service as the password. If you look at your web.config, there will be a `MS_ApplicationKey` app setting, and it will contain the application key that you can use when running locally. You can use anything for the user name (even leave it blank).

Comment: Thank you Carlos!  That makes sense.  I went ahead and used Fiddler to test the POST and GET instead of the mobile service' "tryout" page and works well.